# Char Array to LPCSTR

Tags: c++, arrays, windows

I am struggeling now for days, because I'm very new to c++.

I want to write something into a .ini file with `WritePrivateProfileString`

```
int i = 0;
char arr[total];
stringstream ssin(configs);
while (ssin.good() && i < total){
    ssin >> arr[i];
    ++i;
};

[...]

WritePrivateProfileString(TEXT("Config"),TEXT("active"),arr[i],path);
```

(total is a int that equals 6 and configs is a string like "text1 text2 text3")

And now I want to seperate every `text (text1, text2, text3)` in to a array so I can u easily use them.

But because `WritePrivateProfileString` uses LPCSTR I cant insert this char array as input.

`[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' [-fpermissive]`

Is there a way to use the char array in the `WritePrivateProfileString` function or how can I convert it so it can be used in this function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: LPCSTR is a `const char *`. The error message explains this already.

Comment: I know. But is there a way to use this array anyway or "convert" this array? - Or how can I use this string (the contet of the array) in the WritePrivateProfielString funtion?

Comment: @Shirotaku the parameter should *likely* be simply `arr`, but you had better terminate that string first.

Comment: Wow - the error says that you tried to pass a single `char`, not a char array. `arr[i]` is a *single character*

Comment: @Shirotaku What do you mean _convert_? You can just use `arr` as Parameter already.

Comment: A char-array decays to a char*, which is directly convertible to a const char*

Comment: The error message doesn't look right, since that parameter is an `LPCTSTR` (note the `T` in the middle) (though it appears that you're building in ANSI mode so it still boils down to `const char *`).  It makes me wonder if, in addition to the other problems, you're using some non-standard copies of the Windows headers.

Comment: @Adrian, since `LPCTSTR` is a preprocessor macro rather than a typedef, wouldn't the compiler have already converted it to `LPCSTR` (or `LPCWSTR` where appropriate) by the time it noticed the conversion error?

Comment: @Harry Johnston:  Perhaps that depends on your compiler.  VC++ shows `LPCTSTR` in the error.  The message the OP quoted clearly isn't from VC++, but they didn't specify whether it was gcc, or clang, or something else.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a dupe.  The question _might_ be about splitting the string, but it's not clear.  It's certainly not _solely_ about splitting the string.  I would have gone with "Unclear what you're asking," but I was holding off hoping the question would be clarified.

Comment: @Adrian, turns out my premise was wrong; `LPCTSTR` is a typedef, at least in the latest SDKs.  D'oh!  (But I believe MinGW and other GCC-based compilers use their own headers, not the Microsoft ones.)  The choice of dupe was based on the OPs comment in response to Panagiotis' answer.  It seems pretty clear that the OP intended `arr[i]` to contain a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `arr[i]` which is a char, not an array, as the third argument. You probably wanted to pass `arr`.

The error says:

> [Error] invalid conversion from **'char'** to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: But arr does contains the whole content of "configs" (text1, text2, text3, tex4, text4) which I wantet to seperate (or am I wrong), so that I one out of it the like text3.

Comment: That's not what you asked in the question. Nor does the code show any splittin.  `arr` is a single string, not an array of strings. Check [Split a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)